# Too many blue screen of death errors on a Dell Inspiron running Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I’m using a Dell Inspiron notebook and have an original copy of Windows 10 installed and for the past 10 days my notebook  has been getting a lot of blue screen of death errors, one after the other, which is just making it impossible to do any work. I even reset it to factory settings and it did not fix anything.

Here are the following errors I'm getting:

- Kernel security check failure;
- Kmode exception not handled;
- IRQL not less or equal;
- System service exception;
- memory management;
- Unexpected kernel mode trap;
- Driver overran stack buffer.

What can I do to fix these problems?

Comment: Given you have so many different ones, I wonder how many are secondary.  I would suggest it might be worth seeing if you can generate a more consistent bugcheck code or a more limited set at least by enabling driver verifier.  To do so, run verifier.exe. Use `Create standard settings" - "Select driver names from a list" - on the next page sort by Provider.  Maybe check all those that are Microsoft.  Hopefully, it will be no more than 25-30. Restart the computer, maybe see what code you get next. To disable again re-run and choose "delete existing settings".  We probably then need a dump file.

Comment: Do you have any files under C:\Windows\minidump\ you could share?  Ideally after enabling Verifier and ideally a few especially if they are of different bugcheck codes.  It may be that a complete/active dump is required but this would be a starting point.

Comment: @HelpingHand I followed all the steps to run the verifier.exe and restarted the pc. I just checked the minidump and there is empty.

Comment: Did it bugcheck yet since you enabled verifier? To guarantee a dump, you can always run: `Sysdm.cpl`, Click on the `Advanced` tab - Startup and recovery settings - Choose small memory dump - do you then get the file %SystemRoot%\MEMORY.DMP on the next bugcheck?  Can you share it?  Ideally, we would go for complete/active but these can be as big as your RAM so hard to share.  The mini dumps might provide enough insight as a first check.

Comment: @HelpingHand after the verifier there was no window or pop up notifying me of a bugcheck. Now I chose the small memory dump and the memory.dmp did show up on the systemroot. What should I do next?

Comment: wait until you next get a bugcheck, with verifier on it will hopefully capture (in the dump file) the root cause rather than a secondary problem.

Comment: @HelpingHand and this bugcheck is automatically going to happen? what should I expect to see?

Comment: Bugcheck is an alternative name for a Blue Screen Of Death (BSOD). They are the same thing really.  On an Insider build it's a Green Screen of Death (GSOD I suppose) - bugcheck is a more generic/professional term.

Comment: @HelpingHand got it, thanks for all the help so far. I'll let you know next time a bugcheck happens.

Comment: @HelpingHand ok so it happened again, and two files appeared: one in C: called DUMP2d88.tmp and another on C:/Windows/Minidump called 121719-13718-01.dmp. What do I do now?

Comment: Can you share the .dmp file so it can be analysed?

Comment: @HelpingHand forgive my utter and complete lack of knowledge, but how should I share this file?

Comment: Do you have onedrive, google drive etc.  Otherwise there are a number of free services, a quick google came up with: https://gofile.io/ which might do.

Comment: @HelpingHand oh you meant literally shraing the file, I thought you meant like opening it with some decrypting software or something like that. Sure I'll just upload it to google drive and share the link.

Comment: @HelpingHand here you go https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fsDsEFMLBqKpBhRmDFZYrMHdiBkeJpfU?usp=sharing It's on a compressed file

Comment: I have taken a look at the 3 dumps and added some info here about them - https://pastebin.com/GKRWS7zj Sadly they are all different and don't really point towards anything. We have SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION, SPECIAL_POOL_DETECTED_MEMORY_CORRUPTION and DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUA. The SPECIAL_POOL_DETECTED_MEMORY_CORRUPTION dump seemed like it would be the most useful given verifier is enabled but the stack that ended in nt!KeBugCheckEx just isn't that insightful. At this point, I think some sort of memory test would be useful. Have you tried running mdsched.exe for example?

Comment: @HelpingHand I haven't but I'll run it now and see what happens

Comment: @HelpingHand of I ran the mdsched.exe, what now? Where can I check the results?

Comment: Anything on screen when you run it, otherwise System event log - https://windowsreport.com/mdsched-exe-windows-10/